# Check if a field exists in all the elements of an array in MongoDB and return the documents that contain it

Tags: mongodb

For a sample document like below

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("58f5ae159dfbbf2c98041952"),
 "patient" : {
  "drug" : [ 
 {
    "drugstartdate" : "20151007",
    "actiondrug" : "1",
    "openfda": {
     //some fields here
    }
 },
 {
  //details of one more drug that may or may not contain openfda field
 }
 ]
},
{//Second report
},.....
```

how to return documents(reports) that contain "openfda" sub-document for all the drug elements in drug array? Tried the following:

```
db.getCollection('collname').find({"patient.drug":
{$elemMatch:{"openfda":
{$exists:true}
}
}
})
```

$elemMatch will return all reports where *atleast one* drug contains "openfda" field. Also tried:

```
db.getCollection('BigFDAData_05_06').find({"patient.drug":
{$all:["openfda"]}})
```

But the above returns nothing. What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$elemMatch` query operator. There is no direct query operator to address your case.

```
db.collname.find( { "patient.drug":  { $not: { $elemMatch: { openfda: {$exists:false} } } } } )
```

`"$elemMatch" + "$exists:false"`

This part includes all the documents where `patient.drug` array don't have at least one `openfda` embedded document.

`$not`

This part will keep the all the documents which are not in `"$elemMatch" + "$exists:false"`.

These are all the documents that has its all `drugs` array have `openfda` embedded doc.

Comment: It was a `$not` that was needed! Thanks, @Veeram.