# mongodb query document matching condition in all the array elements?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a gaming app.

In one scenario, I need to find all the documents satisfying the condition in all elements of sub-array(SelectionData).

//Model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const User_Selection = mongoose.Schema({
    UserSelectionID: { type: String, default: "" },
    SelectionData: [
        {
            _id: false,
            match_id: { type: String, default: "" },
            selected_option: { type: String, default: "" },
            selected_points: { type: Number, default: 0 },
            Whether_Points_Calculated: { type: Boolean, default: false },
            Points_Collected: { type: Number, default: 0 }
        }
    ],
    Opponent_Details: {
        USERID: { type: String, default: "" },
        DisplayName: { type: String, default: "" }
    },
    Whether_Final_Points_Calculated: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    Total_Game_Points: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    Status: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    created_at: { type: Date, default: null },
    updated_at: { type: Date, default: null }
}, { collection: 'User_Selection' });
export default mongoose.model('User_Selection', User_Selection);
```

I wish to find all the documents satisfying the condition ("SelectionData.Whether_Points_Calculated" == true) in all array elements.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43778747/2683814

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below script worked for me.

```
db.collection.find({
  "SelectionData": {
    "$not": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "Whether_Points_Calculated": {
          "$eq": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IwUXHSrK6mg)

Answer (score 0):

It shoul be like this

```
const cursor = async() => { 
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                User_Selection.find({
              SelectionData: { Whether_Points_Calculated: true }
          })
         . then(result => {
               resolve(result) 
         }) 
        . catch(err => {  
              reject(err) 
        }) 
}
```

Comment: i want to fetch document where every json array elements will have true

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

db.getCollection('User_Selection').find({"SelectionData":{"$elemMatch":{"Whether_Points_Calculated": true}}})

Comment: i want to fetch document where every json array elements will have true

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{"$match":{"cards":{"$exists":true}}},
{$project: {

    "output": {$filter: {

        input: '$cards' ,

        as: 'arrayElement',

        cond: {"$and":[{$eq: ['$$arrayElement.Whether_Points_Calculated', true]}]}

     }}
  }}
])
```

Comment: i want to fetch document where every json array elements will have true. not with filter returning only true.

Comment: I have updated the correct answer for my case. if you have any other possibility please can post your answer. thank u for being part of this question