# MongoDB - Match if field in array of objects matches query in every object in that array

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB I want to match a document based on whether within an array of documents a certain field matches the query in every document. For example take this document:

```
{ 
"_id" : "2Nh2tnNNH6DgnRvK7", 
"firstName" : "Jim", 
"lastName" : "Bentley", 
"roles" : [
    {
        "_id" : "X8PdRehqXuCWNdXub", 
        "roleName" : "A first one", 
        "applied" : false, 
        "unsuccessful" : false
    },
    {
        "_id" : "X8PdRehqXuCWNdXub", 
        "roleName" : "A second one", 
        "applied" : true, 
        "unsuccessful" : false
    },
    {
        "_id" : "X8PdRehqXuCWNdXub", 
        "roleName" : "A third one", 
        "applied" : true, 
        "unsuccessful" : false
    }
], 
}
```

And I want to return this document only if the applied field is set to false in all documents in the roles array.

How can I do that? Have tried $all and $allElementsTrue but haven't been successful yet.

Thanks

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43778747/2683814

Comment: Thanks that really helped but has surfaced another issue. If my query is now `{roles: { $not: { $elemMatch: { applied: { $eq: true } } }}}` it also matches where roles is an empty array, which i don't want. How can I get it to first check the applied value exists and is false? I've tried wrapping two $not queries in an $and such as below `{ $and: [ { roles: { $not: { $elemMatch: { applied: { $exists: false } } }}}, {roles: { $not: { $elemMatch: { applied: { $eq: true } } }}}]}` but that doesn't work. I've also tried adding the $exists and $eq within the same $elemMatch but no joy

Comment: Np - Try `{roles: { $not: { $elemMatch: { applied: { $eq: true } }, $exists:true }}}`